# Big Book on Fourier Transforms

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, complex-integration

I am looking for a reference that can help me improve my ability to compute complex Fourier Transforms. Is there something like a "Big Book on Fourier Transforms" that has a large number of different typical types of Fourier transforms, worked out examples of how to compute them, and exercises with solutions?

Ideally, something along the lines of **Integration for Calculus, Analysis, and Differential Equations Techniques, Examples, and Exercises**: https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/11035

---

Note: I have seen [Further studies on Fourier Series and Integrals.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/464776/further-studies-on-fourier-series-and-integrals). But I am really looking for more of a reference regarding integration techniques useful for/applied to computing Fourier transforms.

Comment: Try looking in the engineering literature. For example there is this book by Bracewell which might be interesting for you.

Comment: @Giuseppe What book would that be?

Comment: It is called "Fourier transform and applications" or something like that. The author is called Bracewell.

Comment: Bracewell's book is excellent, and even has a chapter entitled "Doing Transforms".  However the book is not exhaustive: e.g.  it will show you how to perform the transform of sgn(x) using contour integration and the Cauchy PV, but it won't teach you about contour integration.  You'll likely also want books on complex analysis, ODEs, PDEs, and signal and system analysis to complement the Bracewell book.

Comment: @AndyWalls Perhaps I can find a copy of it from my university library, but that is the kind of thing I am interested in. Is there anything more exhaustive than his book? Basically, I want to get better at actually computing the transforms, and I'm not really sure where to start or what is actually important.

Comment: I don't know of many dedicated books myself.  I can say this, the most effective method to compute transforms is to use tables of transforms and then theorems to modify the transforms into the one you need.  I rarely resort to the definition.  Bracewell's book goes over the basic theorems and has a nice pictorial table of transforms in the back.

Comment: Take a look at the Bateman Project. https://authors.library.caltech.edu/43489/

Comment: You might consider dropping complex analysis altogether and have a look at the hartley transform.  It is a frequency domain transform equivalent to the Fourier and Laplace transform.